# .htaccess replace parts of the url

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I want the htaccess Redirect 301 to do the following:

```
http://mysite.com/article.php?id=123
```

to

```
http://mysite.com/123
```

Another words, to remove the "article.php?id"part

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

It is important to use `?` in the end to get rid of original query string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `mod_rewrite` if it's enabled:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot that it was php?id= and not php?=